# I would like to know OPC UA tag path format to be used in OPC UA client software

Tags: opc-ua, opc, node-opcua

[image: OPC Tag Access Problem]

I am trying to connect Brodersen RTU OPC UA server with our OPC UA client. Client does not have tag browse option. Instead, valid tag path to be provided in the code. But when I start the client application it throws warning and does not connect.

But same tag can be accessed using other OPC UA software like UAExpert/Kepware. Can anyone pls help me the valid tag path to be given in my client software.

Details in the attached image

Tried different name space values. like 1,2. But still it's not working